# How can I set/remove meta tags?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How do I add meta tags or remove them, for example the default ones added by Drupal core?

I have added the meta tags currently just to the *html.html.twig* file.
There seems to be module which is in beta stage, but if possible, I would like to avoid using third-party modules for this, at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Meta tags module requires you to install three modules:

- Meta tags: http://drupal.org/project/metatag
- CTools: http://drupal.org/project/ctools
- Token: http://drupal.org/project/token

You will see that the Meta Tags module comes with additional modules you can enable it.

Configure Meta Tags Module

[image: Meta Tag Configuration In Drupal]

- Click on Configuration in the black admin menu bar
- Click on Meta tags in the Search and Metadata box on the left side of the screen.

**Notice there are four global settings.**

- Click on each and observe what you get by default. All nodes, terms, and users will have the same configuration by default. But that doesn't have to be the case.

**Now add default Meta Tag.**

- Click on Add a meta tag default.
- Selet Article from the Type dropdown. Enter the token [node:content-type:description] in the abstract field. Save When you create an Article node from now on, the description of the Article content type will appear as such:

[image: Adding Meta Tag]

Now its time to enter the meta tag data with in the site.

[image]

These are some of the basic steps you can follow to add Meta Tag in Drupal. Please follow the steps and let me know if there are any other issue you get.

(Credit: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/meta-tags/)

Comment: so what I have understood from these 2 answers, there is no way to set meta tags without 3rd party module ?

Comment: Yes you need to add 3rd party module, I have already mention about above. Just you need to follow the steps then you will easily configure the meta tags.

Comment: In my honest opinion, you should at least mention the Source from where you are taking these information, or at least mention their source and should state that I  have referred from there and Expressing in my language. Even you have taken images "as is". https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/meta-tags/

Answer (score 0):

**Enable the modules**

The Meta tags module requires you to install three modules:

- Meta tags: http://drupal.org/project/metatag
- CTools: http://drupal.org/project/ctools
- Token: http://drupal.org/project/token

You will see that the Meta Tags module comes with additional modules you can enable, depending on the needs of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the THEME_preproces_html hook in your theme's .theme file to add a META-TAG
for example:

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
$viewport = [
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => [
      'name' => 'viewport',
      'content' => 'user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1',
    ],
  ];
  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
}
```

Will get you this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late maybe. But if you just want to get rid of these meta-tags, you can do it simply in your THEMENAME.theme file:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {

  $unset_meta = [
    'system_meta_generator', // Generator tag
    'MobileOptimized', // MobileOptimized tag
    'HandheldFriendly', // HandheldFriendly tag
  ];

  foreach ($page['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value[1], $unset_meta)) unset($page['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
  }
}
```